# How to block ads of the youtube player for safari?

Tags: macos, youtube, safari, advertisements

I tried many extensions for safari, and also tried blocking via hosts file on mac, but the ads within the youtube videos are still not blocked.

Do these ads not come from pagead2.googlesyndication.com?
Howto block the ads on youtube for safari?

Answer (score 0):

I know product recommendations are frowned on here, but in this case there's no substitute for [AdGuard](https://adguard.com/en/adguard-safari/overview.html), freeware, App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You need third-party products to help, that is if you don't wish to pay Youtube
for an ads-free experience.

See for example the free extension
[AdBlock for Safari](https://getadblock.com/safari/).

Comment: AdBlock stopped working on YouTube a while ago, that's when I switched to AdGuard. I would presume over time & as YT keeps changing their algorithm, one or the other will catch up first.I'll probably swap back if the same happens again.